# input type date, jQuery val() returns element tag and not value

Tags: jquery, html, variables, date, input

I have a simple input tag:

```
<input type="date" class="basic_txt" name="date_birth" id="npdl_dBirth" value=""/>
```

And I need to assign the value of this input to a variable:

```
ndpl_dBirth = $('#npdl_dBirth').val();
```

For some reason this is returning whole tag in a console when I try to print the variable out:

```
console.log(npdl_dBirth);
```

is returning this:

```
<input type="date" name="date_birth" id="r_date_birth" value>
```

I must be missing something really obvious, but can't find out what. Anyone any ideas?
Thx in advance.

Thank you for your help, just found my mistake, simply misspelled the variable. Thx anyway

Comment: Show us your Full `html` ans `js` code. Or make a **Fiddle** of your code.

Comment: When your control has a date it also returns the object ? Is your jquery version the latest ?

Comment: Works on a quick jsFiddle. Is `npdl_dBirth` defined elsewhere in the HTML as well?

Comment: You can try using `ndpl_dBirth = $('#npdl_dBirth').attr('value');`

Comment: Thx guys found my mistake, simply misspelled the variable... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some browsers use the id of elements as global variables, so since `npdl_dBirth` is the id of the input it will be set as a global variable referencing that variable. Try using a different variable name.

Also your variable is `ndpl_dBirth` but you try to print `npdl_dBirth`

Comment: Indeed, internet explorer automatically create variables with the id name of the elements, forgot that, geez

Comment: Cool, didn't know this happened! Interesting for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should  change you `variable name`, it should be different from your `html element id`

```
console.log($('#npdl_dBirth').val());
```

Will work fine in your `case`

**or**

```
var nb=$('#npdl_dBirth').val();
console.log(nb);
```